# Is it possible to create a rolling average in SQL that resets based on another column value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with data that contains gas concentrations from different locations. My goal is to create a rolling average for each location's two week sample periods. My problem is that I know how to use the window function, but I dont know how to make the window reset whenever the location id changes.

[Picture of the desired output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dix3q.jpg)
Ideally, there would be a moving average for each location ID that restarts when it hits the next location ID. I have torn apart the internet looking for a solution, so I'm hoping that a specific question might help me find the answer.
If you need more information, please let me know and I'll give whatever else I can. Thank you!

Comment: *"but I dont know how to make the window reset whenever the location id changes."* Add a `PARTITION BY` clause? You forgot to include your current attempt(s), along with sample data (in a consumable format) and expected results, so we don't know why what you haven't isn't working at the moment.

Comment: Hey man, there isnt any sample code as I havent written this yet. I am new to SQL and have been watching as many videos on all of this as I can. The problem with partition from what I understand is that it cuts down all of the individual rows into one averaged row, and that is not my goal. If theres a way to use partition that doesnt reduce the rows, I would be eager to hear how that works.

Comment: *"The problem with partition from what I understand is that it cuts down all of the individual rows into one averaged row"* this doesn't sound right. Again, consumable sample data, expected results, and your attempts (you must have at least tried *something*) will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
start,
end,
concentration,
location,
AVG(concentration) OVER(PARTITION BY location ORDER BY start) AS rolling_average
FROM <your_table>